# Voxel rendering: pass data from CPU to GPU?

Tags: opengl, voxel

I'm trying to make a voxel-style game, like [Voxatron](https://www.lexaloffle.com/voxatron.php) but I think that my method of rendering is not efficient. The idea is to set the position and color of each voxel and send this data to the GPU each frame. The problem is that if I have a big square of 50x50x50 voxels, I have 125000 * 4 floats * 3 ints to send and it's clearly overloading the CPU-GPU bus (because if I only send the data once for all, I get much more FPS with the same scene). I could do some spatial optimization but my requirement is that each voxel can change arbitrarily each frame so I think it's not worth calculating.

The rendering itself uses the instancied draw of OpenGL so I only draw the voxels set. How can I do that efficiently (I repeat, don't talk me about chunk or whatever, I want the voxels to change arbitrarily each frame anyway). Maybe should I drop OpenGL and do everything in software (like Voxatron)?

Comment: You can try doing all the updates on the GPU with compute.

Comment: what data are you sending per voxel (`4 floats * 3 ints`)? how about using [3D texture instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)?  so you would send just color (`4 BYTEs`).

Comment: @Spektre I send the translation of the voxel (3 ints) and its RGBA color. The translation is needed because of the instanced rendering. But if I use a texture, I will have to send the color of each voxel, even the empty ones? Currently I only send the translation and color of voxels that are set.

Comment: @Jojolatino the idea is to have BBOX like 3D texture for each object, pass its color per voxel (yes even empty ones)  and pass only position and orientation (mat4) of the object once. That should eliminate a lot of data ... Another possibility is to use incremental position encoded voxels ... bacground scene can be resident in GPU and updated its part when needed ...